# Comparar fecha y hora al mismo tiempo en PHP

Tags: php

Para AFIP necesito comprobar que la fecha y hora(momento) de expiracion del certificado sea menor a la actual fecha y hora obviamente.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
$hoy = date("Y-m-jH:i:s"); 

if (file_exists("C:\\xampp\htdocs\gestionweb\includes\php\TAFE.xml")){
   $TA=simplexml_load_file("C:\\xampp\htdocs\gestionweb\includes\php\TAFE.xml");
   $expira=substr($TA->header->expirationTime,0,-10);
   $ec=str_replace('T','',$expira);
  var_dump($hoy);
  var_dump($ec);
   if ($ec<$hoy){
    echo $ec;

    $SERVICE="wsfe";
    CreateTRA($SERVICE);
    $CMS=SignTRA();
    $TA=CallWSAA(base64_decode($CMS));
    if (!file_put_contents("TAFE.xml", $TA)) {exit();}

   }}
```

Con ese codigo porngo la condicion y comparo si la fecha de expiracion es menor a hoy.
Los valores devuelto por los dump son:

```
string(18) "2019-01-1009:07:30" string(18) "2019-01-1003:03:04"
```

Es decir esta la fecha y hora juntos.

El problema es que falla la primera vez del dia como en este momento. la fecha es la misma pero con hora distinta. Y deberia solicitar un nuevo certificado pero no lo hace

No se de que manera debo hacer la comprobacion, o debo separar la fecha y si es la misma comparar la hora?

Comment: Están juntos porque así lo estás creando, por ejemplo: `$hoy = date("Y-m-jH:i:s"); ` deberías poner un espacio: `$hoy = date("Y-m-j H:i:s");` y yo usaría `DateTime` directamente. Para el otro valor, ponlo así: `$ec=str_replace('T',' ',$expira);`

Comment: Poniendo el espacio, PHP compara tanto fecha como hora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `DateTime`  directamente para crear ambos objetos y compararlos. Haciéndolo así no necesitas sustituir la `T` por ejemplo y la creación de la fecha/hora actual se harían con `new` simplemente.

Por ejemplo:

```
$dtz=new DateTimeZone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
$expira="2019-01-10T03:03:04"; #Dato de prueba según tu var_dump
$hoy=new DateTime('now',$dtz);
$ec =new DateTime($expira,$dtz);
var_dump($ec<$hoy);

if ( $ec<$hoy ){

       //...
}
```

En este caso el resultado del `var_dump` sería:

```
bool(true)
```